# deleting tuple elements based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, math

Data frame with DST values:

```
data0 = pd.DataFrame({'DST':[33,11,-52,7,80,34,41,68,-87],'Date':['1975-01-03','1975-01-04','1975-01-07','1975-01-08','1975-01-13','1975-01-14','1975-01-15','1975-02-01','1975-02-03']})
data0
    DST       Date
0   33  1975-01-03
1   11  1975-01-04
2  -52  1975-01-07
3    7  1975-01-08
4   80  1975-01-13
5   34  1975-01-14
6   41  1975-01-15
7   68  1975-02-01
8  -87  1975-02-03
```

Tuples I have:

```
combined_date = [('1975-01-03', '1975-01-06'),('1975-01-13', '1975-01-15'),
                 ('1975-01-31', '1975-02-02'),('1975-02-03', '1975-02-13')]
```

**Problem:**
I have to remove tuple element if DST falls below -50 between those dates in tuple.
I tried the code:

```
for i in len(data0):
    if data0['DST'][i]<-50:
        del (j for j in combined_date if data0['DATE'][i]>=j[0] and data0['DATE'][i]<=j[1])
```

**Expected Output:**

```
('1975-01-03', '1975-01-06'),('1975-01-13', '1975-01-15'),
('1975-01-31', '1975-02-02')
```

Error occuring:can't delete generator expression.

**NOTE**

if DST finds below -50 then that tuple must be deleted!

Comment: @jezrael thanks for pointing the mistakes. Here is edited one.

Comment: because in that interval DST falls below -50. At 1975-02-03, DST is < - 50

Comment: Actually my data is in every minute. So i cant upload sample data. For example for 1 month i have 31*24*60 rows. Any idea for sample df?

Comment: Sorry, I check your code again and now it is perfectly, I miss you change also `combined_date` :(

Answer (score 1):

First filter rows by condition in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
data0['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data0['Date'])
df = data0[data0['DST']<-50]
print (df)
   DST       Date
3  -67 1975-01-07
4  -80 1975-01-15
```

And then remove values of tuples in list comprehension with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
out = [j  for j in combined_date if not df['Date'].between(j[0], j[1]).any()]
print (out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code from the parser's view:

```
del (j for j in combined_date if ...)
```

The parentheses enclose a generator.  What does it mean to delete a generator expression?

What you *want* to do is to delete elements of your list.  The most effective way to do this, in most applications, is to flip your logic and *keep* the elements you want.  Instead of deleting ...

```
kept_date = [j for j in combined_date if ...]
```

Can you take it from there?